# N+1 Hibernate Issue with Bidirectional OneToOne mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I'm using JPARepository with hibernate to represent my database. I have several entities and two of my entities have a bidirectional OneToOne mapping. Whenever I run a query on the child class of the bidirectional relationship (or the parents class to get the child class) - I'm faced with the N+1 hibernate issue.

My parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION")
public class Organization {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_source_id")
    private OrganizationSource source;

    //other columns then getters and setters
}
```

Child class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION_SOURCE")
public class OrganizationSource {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="source", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private Organization organization;

    //other columns then getters and setters
}
```

I then have my DAO class in order to create the query. I used the @Query annotation

```
public interface OrganizationSourceDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<OrganizationSource, Long> {



@Query("SELECT source FROM OrganizationSource source RIGHT JOIN source.organization"
            + "WHERE source.name like %:name% "
    //   order by part of the query
    )
    Page<OrganizationSource> findByNameContaining(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @PageableDefault(size = 10) Pageable pageable);
    }
```

Executing the query in the DAO shows the following in the log

```
Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_6_, organizati0_.city as city2_6_, organizati0_.code as code3_6_, organizati0_.name as name4_6_, organizati0_.source_system_id as source_s5_6_, organizati0_.state as state6_6_, organizati0_.street as street7_6_, organizati0_.uuid as uuid8_6_, organizati0_.zip as zip9_6_ from organization_source organizati0_ right outer join organization organizati1_ on organizati0_.id=organizati1_.organization_source_id where (organizati0_.name like ?) and (organizati0_.state like ?) and (organizati0_.city like ?) order by case ? when 'ASC' then case ? when 'name' then organizati0_.name when 'state' then organizati0_.state when 'city' then organizati0_.city when 'zip' then organizati0_.zip when 'street' then organizati0_.street end end ASC, case ? when 'DESC' then case ? when 'name' then organizati0_.name when 'state' then organizati0_.state when 'city' then organizati0_.city when 'zip' then organizati0_.zip when 'street' then organizati0_.street end end DESC offset 0 rows fetch next ? rows only
Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_4_1_, organizati0_.mfa_method_id as mfa_meth4_4_1_, organizati0_.organization_source_id as organiza5_4_1_, organizati0_.status_id as status_i6_4_1_, organizati0_.uuid as uuid2_4_1_, organizati0_.version as version3_4_1_, organizati1_.id as id1_6_0_, organizati1_.city as city2_6_0_, organizati1_.code as code3_6_0_, organizati1_.name as name4_6_0_, organizati1_.source_system_id as source_s5_6_0_, organizati1_.state as state6_6_0_, organizati1_.street as street7_6_0_, organizati1_.uuid as uuid8_6_0_, organizati1_.zip as zip9_6_0_ from organization organizati0_ left outer join organization_source organizati1_ on organizati0_.organization_source_id=organizati1_.id where organizati0_.organization_source_id=?
Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_4_1_, organizati0_.mfa_method_id as mfa_meth4_4_1_, organizati0_.organization_source_id as organiza5_4_1_, organizati0_.status_id as status_i6_4_1_, organizati0_.uuid as uuid2_4_1_, organizati0_.version as version3_4_1_, organizati1_.id as id1_6_0_, organizati1_.city as city2_6_0_, organizati1_.code as code3_6_0_, organizati1_.name as name4_6_0_, organizati1_.source_system_id as source_s5_6_0_, organizati1_.state as state6_6_0_, organizati1_.street as street7_6_0_, organizati1_.uuid as uuid8_6_0_, organizati1_.zip as zip9_6_0_ from organization organizati0_ left outer join organization_source organizati1_ on organizati0_.organization_source_id=organizati1_.id where organizati0_.organization_source_id=?
Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_4_1_, organizati0_.mfa_method_id as mfa_meth4_4_1_, organizati0_.organization_source_id as organiza5_4_1_, organizati0_.status_id as status_i6_4_1_, organizati0_.uuid as uuid2_4_1_, organizati0_.version as version3_4_1_, organizati1_.id as id1_6_0_, organizati1_.city as city2_6_0_, organizati1_.code as code3_6_0_, organizati1_.name as name4_6_0_, organizati1_.source_system_id as source_s5_6_0_, organizati1_.state as state6_6_0_, organizati1_.street as street7_6_0_, organizati1_.uuid as uuid8_6_0_, organizati1_.zip as zip9_6_0_ from organization organizati0_ left outer join organization_source organizati1_ on organizati0_.organization_source_id=organizati1_.id where organizati0_.organization_source_id=?
Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_4_1_, organizati0_.mfa_method_id as mfa_meth4_4_1_, organizati0_.organization_source_id as organiza5_4_1_, organizati0_.status_id as status_i6_4_1_, organizati0_.uuid as uuid2_4_1_, organizati0_.version as version3_4_1_, organizati1_.id as id1_6_0_, organizati1_.city as city2_6_0_, organizati1_.code as code3_6_0_, organizati1_.name as name4_6_0_, organizati1_.source_system_id as source_s5_6_0_, organizati1_.state as state6_6_0_, organizati1_.street as street7_6_0_, organizati1_.uuid as uuid8_6_0_, organizati1_.zip as zip9_6_0_ from organization organizati0_ left outer join organization_source organizati1_ on organizati0_.organization_source_id=organizati1_.id where organizati0_.organization_source_id=?
Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_4_1_, organizati0_.mfa_method_id as mfa_meth4_4_1_, organizati0_.organization_source_id as organiza5_4_1_, organizati0_.status_id as status_i6_4_1_, organizati0_.uuid as uuid2_4_1_, organizati0_.version as version3_4_1_, organizati1_.id as id1_6_0_, organizati1_.city as city2_6_0_, organizati1_.code as code3_6_0_, organizati1_.name as name4_6_0_, organizati1_.source_system_id as source_s5_6_0_, organizati1_.state as state6_6_0_, organizati1_.street as street7_6_0_, organizati1_.uuid as uuid8_6_0_, organizati1_.zip as zip9_6_0_ from organization organizati0_ left outer join organization_source organizati1_ on organizati0_.organization_source_id=organizati1_.id where organizati0_.organization_source_id=?
Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_4_1_, organizati0_.mfa_method_id as mfa_meth4_4_1_, organizati0_.organization_source_id as organiza5_4_1_, organizati0_.status_id as status_i6_4_1_, organizati0_.uuid as uuid2_4_1_, organizati0_.version as version3_4_1_, organizati1_.id as id1_6_0_, organizati1_.city as city2_6_0_, organizati1_.code as code3_6_0_, organizati1_.name as name4_6_0_, organizati1_.source_system_id as source_s5_6_0_, organizati1_.state as state6_6_0_, organizati1_.street as street7_6_0_, organizati1_.uuid as uuid8_6_0_, organizati1_.zip as zip9_6_0_ from organization organizati0_ left outer join organization_source organizati1_ on organizati0_.organization_source_id=organizati1_.id where organizati0_.organization_source_id=?
```

I've looked at using the annotation `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` and all those quick to solve the solutions available on Google - can't seem to fix this problem though.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN FETCH is the way to go

Comment: I get the following error when I tried that: `query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=organization,role=OrganizationSource.organization,tableName=organization,tableAlias=organizati1_,origin=organization_source organizati0_,columns={organizati0_.id ,className=Organization}}]`

Comment: can you use JOIN FETCH or LEFT JOIN FETCH

Comment: No form of fetch worked for me - even after following the "proper" conventions

Answer (score 0):

I know one trick. Change mapping of Organization from OneToOne to  ManyToOne. This works fine all the time for me. NO n+1 query this time.

OrganizationSource

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION_SOURCE")
public class **OrganizationSource** {

 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
 @Id
 private Long id;

 @JsonBackReference
 @Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Organization organization;

 private String name;
}
```

And Organization

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION")
public class Organization {

 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
 @Id
 private Long id;

 @JsonManagedReference
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "organization_source_id")
 private OrganizationSource source;

}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I tried it I got an `invalid column name organization_id`. I added a `@JoinColumn(name="id", updatable="false", insertable="false)` to point to id (since that is what the organization table uses as the foreign key. That made the search using the Organization's id. When I put "organization_source_id" it would say not found. When I used JoinTable that worked, but the organization values in the organizationSource was null.